# How to edit a .plist file in an iPhone Xcode application?

Tags: xcode, ios4, plist, edit

I am kind of a newbie to this **Xcode** thing. I have created a Winterboard theme that disables multitasking, but I want to add that function to an Xcode iPhone app. How might I do that?
 The .plist (to be exact) is **/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/N18AP.plist**.
 I am a bit **confused**.
**P.S.** - Don't get mad if this isn't too "well-researched." **:P**
 Thanks for the help!

**P.P.S** - I am using a UISwitch.

**UPDATE:** How do I make a DYLIB?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run your app with **root** permissions.

Alternatively you can write a MobileSubstrate dylib that edits the file. Your app would need to use notifications to talk to the dylib and tell it to change the value in that file.